# Set via C# Powershell Variable

Tags: c#, variables, powershell

I have to set via C# a variable in PowerShell and have to use that variable via C# in Powershell again, my code so far:

```
var command = string.Format("$item = Invoke-RestMethod {0} ", "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/?`$format=json");
var command2 = string.Format("$item.value[0].name");
InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(command);
object namesOne= InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(command2);
```

In this case the output should be:
Products

But this C# doesn't work, i tired also:

```
Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runSpace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

Command invoke = new Command("Invoke-RestMethod");
invoke.Parameters.Add("Uri", "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/?`$format=json");
pipeline.Commands.Add(invoke);

runSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("item", pipeline.Invoke());
var a = runSpace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("item");
Command variable = new Command("Write-Host $item");

pipeline.Commands.Add(variable);
var output = pipeline.Invoke();
```

But it works neither.
Has someone an idea how I could set a variable in Powershell and can work with it in Powershell always via C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regards to setting a variable, your second code block works as expected, the following is a quick test setting **$item** in powershell to **FooBar**, pulling this back and confirming that the value is correct:

```
[Test]
public void PowershellVariableSetTest()
{
    var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runSpace.Open();

    runSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("item", "FooBar");
    var a = runSpace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("item");

    Assert.IsTrue(a.ToString() == "FooBar");
}
```

To work directly on Powershell from C#, the following should do the trick:

```
var command = string.Format("$item = Invoke-RestMethod {0} ", "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/?`$format=json");
var command2 = string.Format("$item.value[0].name");

var powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Commands.AddScript(command);
powershell.Commands.AddScript(command2);
var name = powershell.Invoke()[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't want to get the variable in C#. I want to set it in powershell and then use it in powershell via C#.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it.

Set variable:

```
SessionState.PSVariable.Set("TestVar", "1");
```

Get variable:

```
object myvar = GetVariableValue("TestVar");
```